# Will the number of connections on Redis limit the number of jobs I can execute in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am currently using Sidekiq (free) and Heroku Redis (free) on my Rails app. I noticed that Heroku Redis says it has a connection limit of 20.

Would this affect/limit the number of background jobs I can execute with Sidekiq?

Essentially, all I use Sidekiq for in this app is to send an email for a newsletter. The email is sent out by clicking a button once the newsletter is ready. This button executes the following code from my `EditionsController`:

```
def send_notification
    users = User.all

    users.each do |user|
        EditionMailer.with(edition: @edition, user: user).notification_email.deliver_later
    end

    redirect_to edition_path(@edition)
end
```

I currently have 63 users on the app, so this would send 63 mails. However, I expect more to be added later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unless you specify `RAILS_MAX_THREADS`, `sidekiq` will use around 5 concurrent jobs; that being said, `redis` will never be affected by the number of concurrent max jobs as they are processed in a queuing system. It will process the work by batches of 20

Comment: Oh OK. So, that means that having 20 connections would not stop the emails from going out, but would simply slow it down as more and more emails are sent. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep @UmarGhouse

Answer (score 1):

For sidekiq to work you need a connection from web-server side (aka client) and connection from sidekiq worker (aka server/worker), all these are pooled.

So connection limit affects how many concurrent workers and web server processes/threads you can have. This limits how many jobs can be processed in parallel, not the total jobs count.

Also keep in mind that during deploy you will have double the connections from web dynos (when new ones are already started and old ones still handling connections).

For sidekiq config you can use [calculator by Manuel van Rijn](http://manuelvanrijn.nl/sidekiq-heroku-redis-calc/)